# Maximize the number of nodes that could be reachable in a graph

Tags: java, performance, graph

Description of my code:

I am trying to maximize the number of nodes that could be reachable in a graph. Please do not consider my main algorithm, I want it to be like that. The only parts that I need to be boosted are the way of using data structures and reachability. I don't want to change my main algorithm.

I am looking for boosting the performance of my program. Here is the source code of that. Is there any part that could perform faster? Any little speed up would be great because of this algorithm should be run on a graph with more than 1m nodes.

```
public LinkedHashSet<Customer> retentionSeedFinder(int budget,
        HashSet<Customer> churnerNodes, int delay,
        DirectedSparseGraph<Customer, Transaction> network) {

    LinkedHashSet<Customer> seedSet = new LinkedHashSet<Customer>();
    numberofNodes = network.getVertexCount();
    churnNet = new HashSet<Customer>();
    HashSet<Customer> tmpchurnNet = new HashSet<Customer>();
    HashSet<Customer> availableNodes;
    // at timestep 0

    churnNet.addAll(churnerNodes);
    churnNet.addAll(getNeighbors(churnerNodes, network));

    availableNodes = getReachableNodes(churnNet, network);

    // at timestep 1
    int timestep = 1;
    tmpchurnNet = churnNet;
    while (timestep <= delay) {

        Collection<Customer> neighbors;

        System.out.println("***********************At timestep:" + timestep
                + "*************************");
        for (Customer churner : churnNet) {
            neighbors = network.getNeighbors(churner);
            for (Customer specificNeighbor : neighbors) {
                tmpchurnNet.add(specificNeighbor);
            }
        }
        churnNet = tmpchurnNet;
        timestep++;
    }

    PriorityQueue<Customer> marginalGainHeap = new PriorityQueue<Customer>(
            1, new Comparator<Customer>() {
                public int compare(Customer c1, Customer c2) {
                    if (c1.getMarginalGain() < c2.getMarginalGain())
                        return 1;
                    if (c1.getMarginalGain() > c2.getMarginalGain())
                        return -1;
                    if (c1.getMarginalGain() == c2.getMarginalGain()) {
                        if (c1.getRevenue() < c2.getRevenue())
                            return 1;
                        if (c1.getRevenue() > c2.getRevenue())
                            return -1;
                    }
                    return 0;
                }
            });

    // set of all remains available nodes
    availableNodes.removeAll(churnNet);
    for (Customer avail : availableNodes) {
        avail.setMarginalGain(0);
        marginalGainHeap.add(avail);
    }
    int seedNum = 1;
    while (seedSet.size() < budget) {
        Collection<Customer> tmpAvailNodes = new HashSet<Customer>();
        tmpAvailNodes.addAll(availableNodes);
        for (Customer remainingNode : tmpAvailNodes) {
            remainingNode.setMarginalGain(calculateMarginalGain(
                    remainingNode, seedSet, network, availableNodes,
                    churnNet));

            // heapify bar asase mg
            marginalGainHeap.remove(remainingNode);
            marginalGainHeap.add(remainingNode);
        }
        availableNodes.remove(marginalGainHeap.peek());
        System.out.println(marginalGainHeap.peek().getName());
        seedSet.add(marginalGainHeap.poll());
        System.out
                .println("Target seed subscriber for short-term campaign has been found:"
                        + seedNum++);
    }
    return seedSet;
}

private double calculateMarginalGain(Customer remainingNode,
        HashSet<Customer> seedSet,
        DirectedSparseGraph<Customer, Transaction> net,
        HashSet<Customer> availableNodes, HashSet<Customer> churnNetwork) {
    // Marginal gain for short-term campaign
    HashSet<Customer> tmp = new HashSet<Customer>(); // seedset U
                                                        // {remainingNode}
    tmp.addAll(seedSet);
    tmp.add(remainingNode);
    HashSet<Customer> tmpAvailableNodes = new HashSet<Customer>();
    tmpAvailableNodes.addAll(availableNodes);
    // sigma function for calculating the expected number of influenced
    // customers- seedSettmp=seedset U {u}
    tmpAvailableNodes.removeAll(churnNetwork);
    HashSet<Customer> influencedNet = getNeighbors(tmp, net);
    tmpAvailableNodes.retainAll(influencedNet);
    return tmpAvailableNodes.size();
}

private HashSet<Customer> getNeighbors(HashSet<Customer> churnNetwork,
        DirectedSparseGraph<Customer, Transaction> net) {
    HashSet<Customer> churnNeighbors = new HashSet<Customer>();
    churnNeighbors.addAll(churnNetwork);
    Collection<Customer> neighbors = new HashSet<Customer>();
    for (Customer node : churnNetwork) {
        neighbors = net.getNeighbors(node);
        for (Customer neighbor : neighbors) {
            churnNeighbors.add(neighbor);
        }
    }
    return churnNeighbors;
}

public HashSet<Customer> getReachableNodes(Collection<Customer> startNodes,
        DirectedSparseGraph<Customer, Transaction> graph) {
    Queue<Customer> queue = new LinkedList<Customer>();
    HashSet<Customer> visited = new HashSet<Customer>();
    queue.addAll(startNodes);
    visited.addAll(startNodes);
    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        Customer v = queue.poll();
        Collection<Customer> neighbors = graph.getNeighbors(v);
        for (Customer n : neighbors) {
            if (!visited.contains(n)) {
                queue.offer(n);
                visited.add(n);
            }
        }
    }
    return visited;
}
```

Comment: Have you profiled your code?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve. A quick look says that this is one of those shortest path solution. If yes what is the algorithm that you are using? Please elaborate a *little* about your problem and your solution to get a good review.

Comment: Please, oh please, at least describe what your code does. Including a description of your code makes things so much easier for us.

Comment: I added some description. However I dont want to change my main algorithm. I am looking for changing the way of implementing this algorithm and the used data structures...

Comment: Its a bit difficult to comment on optimizing the topping, if you got half of the cake wrong. Your code has the usual beginner issues: bad structure, bad formatting, strong lack of sub-methods, long "spaghetti" code-parts, no comments, and so much more... So yes it is possible to optimize this code, but you need to be more specific.

Answer (score 4):

Lots to think about, this is not a comprehensive evaluation

### Use Java7

your code style indicates you are using Java6 (you are not using the [diamond operator `<>`](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074080/core-java/jdk-7--the-diamond-operator.html)...).

Java 7 and it's recent updates are faster than Java6.

### Extract the comparator:

```
private static final Comparator<Customer> PRIORITY_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<>() {
            public int compare(Customer c1, Customer c2) {
                if (c1.getMarginalGain() < c2.getMarginalGain())
                    return 1;
                if (c1.getMarginalGain() > c2.getMarginalGain())
                    return -1;
                if (c1.getMarginalGain() == c2.getMarginalGain()) {
                    if (c1.getRevenue() < c2.getRevenue())
                        return 1;
                    if (c1.getRevenue() > c2.getRevenue())
                        return -1;
                }
                return 0;
            }
        }
```

Then use it as:

```
PriorityQueue<Customer> marginalGainHeap = new PriorityQueue<>(1, PRIORITY_COMPARATOR);
```

### LinkedHashSet

Your method returns `LinkedHashSet<Customer>`. This strikes me as odd.... To me this means:

- the order is important
- you don't know what your data does in terms of duplicates.

Using a Set means you expect duplicate data, and you only discover it is a duplicate **after** you have done the work, and you add it to the set.

You should adjust this to be a more natural structure, like a `List<Customer>` and then ensure that you are not processing the same customer twice....

### Dubious Queue Usage

> ```
>     for (Customer remainingNode : tmpAvailNodes) {
>         remainingNode.setMarginalGain(calculateMarginalGain(
>                 remainingNode, seedSet, network, availableNodes,
>                 churnNet));
>
>         // heapify bar asase mg
>         marginalGainHeap.remove(remainingNode);
>         marginalGainHeap.add(remainingNode);
>     }
> ```

`marginalGainHeap` is a Priority queue. It is not a free data structure.

Changing the priority of a value is dubious (I had to check that the `remove()` will actually succeed... It will, but it [performs slowly ( *O(n)* performance )](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html). Because of the way you `remove()` and `add()` ( *O( log n)* ) the same values multiple times, you are running at essentially *O(n<sup>2</sup>log(n))* performance in that section.

### System.out.println

You are doing this a lot.

It is slow.

Don't

### calculateMarginalGain

This method looks horrendous for performance.

- 2 new HashSets
- 4 *O(n)* operations - addAll, addAll, retainAll, removeAll

Call to getNeighbours adds:

- 2 new HashSet
- 1 addAll
- *O(n * m)* loop system

### Conclusion....

You have to change your code to ***NOT do things you have to Undo Later***

- Don't add things to a priority queue if you have to change the priority
- Don't add things to a HashSet if you have to remove them later.
- .....

Comment: I used LinkedHashSet because of I need an ordered set.

Comment: Without using System.out how can I figure out the progress of my program? About "not do things you have to undo late" you meant I should check before adding data? I my case it is impossible because of at the time of insertion I have no idea about this problem.